# Is it possible to make the WiX XmlFile action leave escaped strings alone?

Tags: wix

I'm using WiX's XmlFile action to update a log4net.config file to fill in the log file path. That part works fine, but it's modifying escaped strings in another part of the document.

The config file starts out with this in the PatternLayout spec:

```
<header value="Timestamp&#x9;Thread&#x9;Level&#x9;Logger&#x9;Message&#xD;&#xA;" />
```

But after the XmlFile operation runs, the resulting file after installation looks like this:

```
      <header value="Timestamp  Thread  Level   Logger  Message
"/>
```

Seems like a bug to me, but is there a fix or workaround I might try?

**Edit**: I've opened a WiX bug at http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4971/

Comment: Does your XML-file starts with an xml-tag which defines an Unicode-encoding for the file? Using tabs in an unicode XML-file should be fine. I am expecting that the tabs are encoded again as soon you change the encoding to " iso-8859-1" or similar.

Comment: @StefanWanitzek, the file is marked as utf-8. In any case, the problem is that the log4net sees the unescaped tabs and CRLF sequence and just treats them as spaces. In other words, every tab and CRLF character you see above shows up as a single space in the resulting log file.